# How to create dynamic tables in asp input by user C# asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, dynamic

Want to create dynamic tables input by user

Comment: What is your question exactly? Where is your html code? What did you tried already?

Comment: string cs = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"].ConnectionString;

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);

string sqlStatement = "CREATE TABLE dbo.prince (stuname CHAR(50), stuaddress CHAR(255), stubalance FLOAT)";

con.Open();

SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, con);

sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

con.Close();

Comment: but my code but i want input form user to create dynamic tables columns name etc

Answer (score 0):

You can create your sql query dynamically.

Example

```
Table name: <asp:TextBox id="TextBox1" runat="server" />
Columns: <asp:TextBox id="TextBox2" TextMode="multiline" runat="server" />
```

in code-behind

```
string tableName = TextBox1.Text;
string[] lines = TextBox2.Text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None); 

string cs = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"].ConnectionString; SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs); 
string sqlStatement = "CREATE TABLE dbo."
      + tableName 
      + " (" + string.Join(",", lines) + ")"; 

con.Open(); 
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, con); 
sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
con.Close();
```

where textbox1 is a name of a table e.g. Table1 and textbox2 is a list of columns with their type, e.g.

```
col1 nvarchar(30)
col2 int
col3 text
```

Comment: Columns name should be input by user and its type please guide me

Comment: How by the columns name thats my problem please guide me